# Type Clincher Tire and Tube to mount on tlr rim

Tags: tire

Just acquired a like new set of Paradigm tlr Wheels. They have s-works 2bliss mounted on them now. Using these wheels on a recumbent for pleasure riding. Thinking of using a clincher tire and Tube because I've read that many of the tlr tires are performance oriented and not long lasting. Also not sure I want to go through the maintenance of a tlr setup. Any suggestions on a good Presta Valve tube and tire for my needs? I'm going to try the s-works tlr tire that's on the rim now soon and see what I think but I'm guessing I would rather just go tube and clincher. Maybe I should have just bought a standard style rim

Comment: Just to clarify the question - you want to mount a clincher tyre and tube, onto a rim that is TubeLess Ready (or TLR) correct ?

Comment: Yes that is my plan to mount Clincher and Tube onto a tlr paradigm wheel. I guess I'm looking for a system that would be of highest flat resistance and ease of repairing such flat. The Bontrager Factory supplied plastic Rim strip is already installed on the rim so I would be using that as Rim tape I'm guessing. What type of clincher Tire would be easiest to remove and reinstall in the process of fixing a flat. There is a s-werks tlr Tire installed now and if the tlr system works as it's supposed to I guess Id never have to remove that tire unless it was gashed or worn out. Great advice here

Answer (score 1):

> Thinking of using a clincher tire and Tube because I've read that many of the tlr tires are performance oriented and not long lasting.

This may be a misconception. The higher end of each manufacturer's lineup will inherently be less durable. Within limits, I believe there's a tradeoff between rolling resistance, grip, and durability. You can't maximize all three. Improved technology could enable you to make a leap over the previous generation, but you'd still have a similar tradeoff.

I think that a lot of tires were made in standard clincher and tubeless versions a while ago. Tubeless tires may be coming to dominate the lineups. Remember that you can take a tubeless tire and run it with a tube.

In addition, if you go to a lower end tire, you'll probably have a poorer ride quality due to the less flexible casing, as well as higher rolling resistance.

In my experience, I think that the current top tier racing tires (*not* time trial tires, but the highest tier general purpose tire in a lineup) may have less durability than their predecessors. The Continental Grand Prix 5000 seems to be less durable than the GP 4000, but the 5000 has possibly 2W less rolling resistance per tire. That said, the second tier of tires, e.g. the Continental Grand Prix 5000 AS TR or Vittoria Corsa N.EXT, may have better durability and not much more rolling resistance.

We don't offer product suggestions. Sometimes people make exceptions if they are clearly objectively better than the competition. The GP 5000 is not in that situation, but it is a well-regarded tire and you won't go wrong choosing it or a relative like the AS TR. You should find similar tradeoffs in the top tier manufacturers, e.g. Vittoria, Schwalbe, Michelin. Also, even if the top tier tires have short life, they can still last a long time. I believe I got 3-4000 miles out of my last set of GP 5000s. Depending on mileage, that can be two seasons of riding for some.

For tubes, I am not sure that standard butyl tubes have significant differences between them. It's likely that any standard butyl tube should suffice. When you move to the performance-oriented options like latex or TPU, there are significant tradeoffs. TPU is expensive, and latex requires daily inflation.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should go with the second highest level of Tire in each brand then before my needs. Will a clincher Tire be any easier to remove and reinstall than a tlr tire on a tlr rim? I guess I'm intimidated by the tlr system as a whole compared with old school tubes. I have the rims to use the tlr system so maybe I should try to break myself into it rather than going immediately to a inner tube style setup. Thanks for the great answer Weiwen Ng

Comment: @Michael I would give tubeless a try. IME, a tubeless-ready tire last just as long as it’s non-TLR counterpart, rides better, and avoids so many flat tires.

Comment: Thank you Paul H, I guess I will wade into the water,or sealant, in this case. The S Works turbo rapid air tires were on the Wheels when I bought them and I see they are a real Top Notch grade Tire. I might as well give those a try and see what I think. I guess my biggest concern would be having to insert a tube in case of a catastrophic flat on the trail. One of my friends tells me they are so much harder to take off and put back on a rim. Would a regular Clincher Tire with tube be easier to take off and put back on? Is it the tlr rim itself that makes removing and installing difficult?

Comment: @Michael In my experience, high end tubeless tires and rims are easy to mount and dismount without any tools. Use good sealant. Carry plugs.